# hide the vertical bar in a megento site found on top of the site

Tags: css, magento

there is a small "vertical bar" is displaying before the search box on top of the site.

I can remove entire "search box". but i want to remove only vertical bar.

let me know if you need any clarifications.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at theme.css line 635 :

```
.form-search .input_search {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    background: none;
    min-height: 33px;
}
```

change it to :

```
.form-search .input_search {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-left: none;
    background: none;
    min-height: 33px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
#search_mini_form div.input_search {
    border-left: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your custom styles.css, add the rule:

```
 .header .form-search {
     border-left: none;
 }
```